# Superior limit of integrals of entire functions

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function on $\mathbb{C}$. If $f$ is not constant, then I want to prove

\begin{equation}
\limsup_{R\to\infty}\int_{\lvert z\rvert=R}\lvert f(z)\rvert\,\lvert dz\rvert=\infty.
\end{equation}
Is it correct or not? How to prove?

Note that $|f(z)|$ is not bounded does not imply that the limit of the integral goes to infinity. We need to consider $\mu\big(\big\{\lvert z\rvert=R: f(z)>M\big\}\big)$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is non-constant, there exists an $n\in\mathbb N$, such that $f^{(n)}(0)\ne 0$. According to Cauchy's Integral Formula:
$$
f^{(n)}(0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R}\frac{f(w)\,dw}{w^{n+1}}.
$$
Thus
$$
\left\lvert f^{(n)}(0)\right\rvert\le \frac{n!}{2\pi}
\Big\lvert\int_{|z|=R}\frac{f(w)\,dw}{w^{n+1}}\Big\rvert\le \frac{n!}{2\pi R^{n+1}}\int_{|z|=R}\lvert f(z)\rvert\lvert dz\rvert,
$$
and thus
$$
\int_{|z|=R}\lvert f(z)\rvert\lvert dz\rvert\ge 2\pi R^{n+1}\lvert f^{(n)}(0)\rvert
\to\infty,
$$
as $R\to\infty$.